# Get Git username in R script

Tags: r, git

I’m trying to call the Git username of whoever is running the script in RStudio. I have tried system(“git config —-list user.name”) and system(“git config —-get user.name”) but no luck so far.
Cheers

Comment: Just curious and a stupid question, does `—-` have a special meaning in R? It is not a doubled dash accepted by git.

Comment: Specifically, what does "no luck" mean?

Answer (score 0):

There are functions in `git2r` that might be useful: https://rdrr.io/cran/git2r/

For example to use R to retrieve git commits and the author using the following example code:

```
git2r::last_commit()
pth <- getwd()
lst_commit <- git2r::revparse_single(pth, "HEAD")
lst_commit$author
```